# Adding depth data to ARKit

Tags: arkit

Is there a way to add depth data to a capture in real time. I'd like to add an external time of flight sensor source to an ARKit app, that provides depth information to the rear camera capture for better accuracy on low feature surfaces.

I see "capturedDepthData?", can external sources of data be used to augment capture?

Comment: Do you mean adding your own data to what’s being processed by ARKit?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to use the ARKit framework for the rich toolkit Apple's built, but use an external depth sensor to improve the accuracy of the scene capture.

Answer (score 0):

ARKit knows how to process input from the sources that Apple built it to process: color video and motion data from the built-in cameras and sensors of an iOS device.

ARKit doesn’t know how to process input from arbitrary other sources, so it doesn’t offer a way for you to provide such input.

---

The documentation for the [`capturedDepthData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2928208-captureddepthdata) property you mentioned clarifies that it’s an output, not an input. If you’re using an ARKit configuration that makes use of a device’s built-in depth sensor (that is, face tracking with the TrueDepth camera on iPhone X), ARKit provides the output from that sensor here.